# Multiple row Sums into a Total Column

Tags: sql

I have a temp table populated in a sproc that is similar to this:

```
Company   Col1      Col2     Col3    Total
Company1   4          3        2       9
Company2   1          0        3       4
Total      ?          ?        ?       ?
```

Is there a slick way to get the bottom total column populated with SUM of each row in one shot without having to do each column individually using sub-queries?

Comment: "Bottom total column" should be "bottom total row".

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(col1), sum(col2), sum(col3), sum(col1+col2+col3)
FROM CompanyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

If the DBMS you use is MS SQL than be aware of how to reference the temporary table:

```
SELECT SUM(Col1) as TotalOfCol1,...
FROM #Company
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL, you can get the whole table in one query using the [WITH ROLLUP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) feature:

```
SELECT Company, SUM(Col1), SUM(Col2), SUM(Col3), SUM(Col1 + Col2 + Col3)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Company
WITH ROLLUP
```

Results:

```
'Company1'  4  3  2  9
'Company2'  1  0  3  4
''          5  3  5 13  <--- This extra row is the column totals
```